# Best drag and drop GUI builder for wxPython

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

What is the best drag and drop GUI builder for wxPython? 
I've tried wxGLade, but I strongly dislike it.

Comment: If you read a few other questions on this site, you may notice that it's considered good form to explain **why** the tool you tried was not to your liking, so that answerers have a chance to help you. Otherwise, your question is subjective and will be closed. Also, "Thanks in advance guys" in your question isn't necessary, and neither is "lol".

Comment: I am trying to tell you how etiquette works on this site, and why your question is, with the best will in the world, difficult to answer in its current state. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just starting out on GUI programming in Python I'll strongly recommend ditching wxPython for PySide/PyQt4. It has a simpler API and Qt-Designer is one of the best drag 'n' drop GUI designer I've used. Plus PySide/PyQt4 is well documented.